# How to use keyboard shortcuts to launch n'th item in task manager in KDE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, gui

I want to be able to launch the n'th item in my "Icons-only Task Manager" widget (included in KDE by default) using the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+[N]. For example, if my panel looks like this:[image: launcher, search, open chrome, file manager, minimised konsole]
I want to be able to activate Chrome using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, and launch a new Dolphin (file manager) window using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, because they are the first and second items in my task manager respectively. This is similar to the functionality in Windows.

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 64-Bit with KDE Plasma 5.5.5 and Qt 5.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was not possible at the time I posted this question, but this is now a feature by default in KDE. You can change the shortcuts in System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Plasma -> Activate Task Manager Entry 1 .. 10